# how to communicate with sqlserver using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know we cannot communicate with sqlserver using jquery "directly" but I want to know about the indirect method
I am working on a project with the following scenario

1. a jquery script which is installed in the browser and when it is installed and the user opens a web page and hovers the mouse pointer over an image the script runs to check whether the image has  an alternate text or not.If not it will tell the user there is no alternate text and a dialog box will open(which is a div in the html)
2. the dialog box has
         *textbox
         *cancel button
         *submit button
3. now, in the submit button's code I would like the code to send that text into my database.
   I heard somewhere that we can transmit that text (from the textbox as entered by the user) using ajax to an aspx page on my website

But i dont know how
here is some code for convenience to understand the scenario
also there is no Id for the buttons,only classes :(

```
Cancel:
function(){
    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
}

$( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 300,
    width: 350,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
    "Send your proposal": function() {
    var ID=this.id;
    //alert(ID);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ON the aspx page you can add a webMethod like this.

```
[WebMethod()]
public void SAveAltTExt(string text)
{
    //Save text to db
}
```

then you call this with jquery ajax functions like this

```
$.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        data: "{ text: '" + $("[id$='txtTextValue']").val() + "'}",
                        url: "AspxPage.aspx/SAveAltTExt",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (data) {
                          //Do what you want
                        },
                        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                            //Handle error
                        }
```

Comment: i am working on IIS do I need to provide the full path here like
http:/localhost:2020/aspxpage.aspx?

Comment: no if its calling the same aspx page just use as above.  The paths are relative to the current file location.

Comment: actually script is working on any random page and the data need to be transferred form it to my web server that is why i am asking

Comment: you put the code in a script tag on the page which is makiong the ajax request.  I would guess on some button click event.  $("#somebutton").click(function (e) { ajax call here });

Comment: it is in the script only
moreover the button is not having an ID rather it is something like this
$( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
  
   height: 300,
   width: 350,
   modal: true,
   buttons: {
    "Send your proposal": function() {
     
     
 

    $.ajax({
        url: "Alternate.aspx",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       dataType: "json",
       
        success: function () {
            //
        }
    });

using inspect element i found this for the submit button

<button type="button" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all">Send your proposal</button>

Comment: the button id is not known the class name is known just